# Create SpatialLine from elongated buffer

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` which is the buffer of a road. I would like to recreate the approximate path of this road by finding the `SpatialLine` that fits inside that buffer.

Any idea on how to do this?

#### reproducible example

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

line <- readWKT("LINESTRING(0 0, 0.2 0.1, 0.3 0.6, 0.4 0.1, .3 .3, 1 1)")

# buffer
  line_buff <- gBuffer(line, width = 0.01)
  plot(line_buff, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A really *long-shot*, but you might be able to magic something up by triangulating to the right size, then finding paths through the centroids of those, but I don't like the chances when the routes actually self-intersect like this ...

```
tri <- sfdct::ct_triangulate(sf::st_as_sf(line_buff), a = 0.0005)
plot(st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_cast(tri$geometry))))
```